# How to download the final url from the campaign level in Google Ads API using GAQL query

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I am trying to get data for the conversion and the assigned final url using Google Ads API & GAQL. From what I saw, it is possible to click such a report using graphical tools, but in the API I do not see any way of combining this type of data into one report.

From the campaign level, it is not possible to simply add the final url field.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v7/campaign_query_builder

So my question is: \how can I get conversion data + final url from Google Ads using GAQL or AdsApp?

My current code, or rather query, looks like this:

```
...
var report_conversion = AdsApp.report(
  "SELECT campaign.name, " +
  "segments.conversion_action_name, " +
  "metrics.conversions, metrics.conversions_value" + 
  "FROM campaign WHERE segments.date > '2021-01-01' AND segments.date < '2021-01-31'"
);

report_conversion.exportToSheet(sheet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the final URL is not a campaign attribute/resource. It's an attribute of an ad.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v8/Ad

```
report_request = f'''SELECT ad.final_urls[]
                            FROM Ad'''
```

Think of what you're doing as querying the campaigns table, when you really want to query the Ad table. Be aware that not all metrics are available at this level.